# How Can I Deflect The Scanned IP Address to The Honeypots?

Tags: security, networking, honeypot

I never use honeypot before. But, I have a task from my lecture, that I should use a honeypot for detecting hackers attacks.

I searched in journals, tutorials and articles. I tried using `honeydrive3` and used the honeypot Kippo. When I tried that, and I attack by myself, it works, the detailed of attack is served. But, when I told that to my lecturer, he said it was not what he wanted.

The workflow he want is, we use the honeypot and then we try that to some websites. But, when the attacker scanning or do something to that web IP address, it must deflect to the honeypot, it means that the attacker really attacks the real website.. and I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Unless you really, really know what you are doing, you can easily make your network _more_ vulnerable. Honeypots should be left to experts. You should ask about this on [security.se].

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Answer (score 1):

You either misunderstood what the lecturer wanted, or what he wants does not make sense.

You can only analyze traffic sent to your IP (or an IP you control), it is not possible for you to "deflect the traffic" from a generic IP address.

What you did is correct: putting in place the honeypot, and then sending some traffic to it.

The next step would be to expose it to Internet to get malicious traffic (directed to **your** IP) but you must be very careful as the whole machine is likely going to get successfully attacked. It must not have any connection to your (home|uni|private) network, because (I am being frank reading your question), you stand no chance to secure it for the time being.

I would go for a cloud hosted machine which I would then kill.